# Show a ComboBox based on the selected value of another ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a little problem - I want to show a "sub Combobox" with the help of a "super Combobox". I don't know it is possible because i'm beginner in VB.

My English is not so good so please see the below code to understand me :)

```
If combobox1.SelectedItem = "PAKISTAN" Then
    combobox2.Visible = True
End If

If combobox1.SelectedItem = "INDIA" Then
    combobox3.visible = True
    combobox2.visible = False
End If
```

Obviously this code is wrong, but it is an example of what I want to do.

Thanks to all in advance.